# "Load More Buttons" not working with two seperate lists ".each" properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, node.js

I want to make two load more buttons that load the specific list that they are connected too with `id` or `class` or etc. So far my code populates the lists incorrectly for example when i click the `view more complete`-> `reservations_completed` button on my page it will load a duplicate of itself on the other `list`/ `.each` called `reservations_pending`. Even with these classes/id's that are suppose to keep them "seperated".

- The problem i believe is one of two:

1)  in the http request that it sends, it uses page=2 or whatever so i think both the `complete` and `pending` are being set to that page when either button is pressed resulting in that problem happening.

2) another possible problem could be in the `js.erb file` I could be calling append wrong with the clicks or whatever I have no idea at this point as i tried many combinations of things and have not gotten this to work, my brain needs some help!!

Now if there is another way that is easier or just another way of doing this period please let me know show me the way im learning so much!!!

**your_essays.html.erb:**

```html
<div id="content-load-more-completed">
  <%= render 'your_essays_completed', reservations_completed: @reservations_completed %>
   </div>

<% unless @reservations_completed.current_page == @reservations_completed.total_pages %>
  <div class="view-more-completed" class="center" style="min-width:100%;" >
    <%= link_to('View More', url_for(page_completed: @reservations_completed.current_page + 1), remote: true, class: 'btn btn-back', style: 'min-width:100%;') %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<div id="content-load-more-expired">
  <%= render 'your_essays_expired', reservations_expired: @reservations_expired %>
  </div>

  <% unless @reservations_expired.current_page == @reservations_expired.total_pages %>
  <div class="view-more-expired" class="center" style="min-width:100%;" >
    <%= link_to('View More', url_for(page_expired: @reservations_expired.current_page + 1), remote: true, class: 'btn btn-back', style: 'min-width:100%;') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**your_essays.js.erb**

```js
$('.view-more-completed a').click(function (event) {
$('#content-load-more-completed').append("<%=j render 'your_essays_completed', reservations_completed: @reservations_completed, format: 'html' %>");
});
<% if @reservations_completed.current_page == @reservations_completed.total_pages %>
  $('.view-more-completed').remove();
<% else %>
  $('.view-more-completed a').attr('href', '<%= url_for(page_completed: @reservations_completed.current_page + 1) %>');
<% end %>

$('.view-more-expired a').click(function (event) {
$('#content-load-more-expired').append("<%=j render 'your_essays_expired', reservations_expired: @reservations_expired, format: 'html' %>");
});

<% if @reservations_expired.current_page == @reservations_expired.total_pages %>
  $('.view-more-expired').remove();
<% else %>
  $('.view-more-expired a').attr('href', '<%= url_for(page_expired: @reservations_expired.current_page + 1) %>');
<% end %>
```

**Reservation_controller**

```rails
def your_essays

    user = current_user
  @reservations = user.reservations.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).where("status = ?", true)

  #pending
  @reservations_pending = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).where("due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page_pending]).per_page(3)

   @reservations_pending1 = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).where("due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).order(created_at: :desc)

  #completed

  @reservations_completed = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", true).where("completed_doc_updated_at <= due_date", true).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page_completed]).per_page(3)
  @reservations_completed1 = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", true).where("completed_doc_updated_at <= due_date", true).order(created_at: :desc)
  #expired
  @reservations_expired = user.reservations.where("due_date <= ?", DateTime.now).where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page_expired]).per_page(3)
  @reservations_expired1 = user.reservations.where("due_date <= ?", DateTime.now).where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).order(created_at: :desc)


end
```

**load-more.js**

```js
//completed

$(function() {
  var content, isLoadingNextPage, lastLoadAt, loadNextPageAt, minTimeBetweenPages, viewMore;
  content = $('#content-load-more-completed');
  viewMore = $('.view-more-completed');
  isLoadingNextPage = false;
  lastLoadAt = null; 
  minTimeBetweenPages = 5000;
  return loadNextPageAt = 1000;


var nextPage;

nextPage = function() {
  var isLoadingNextPage, lastLoadAt, url;
  url = viewMore.find('.view-more-completed a').attr('href');
  if (isLoadingNextPage || !url) {
    return;
  }
  
  isLoadingNextPage = true;
  lastLoadAt = new Date();
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function() {
      
      isLoadingNextPage = false;
      return lastLoadAt = new Date();
    }
  });
};

viewMore.find('.view-more-completed a').click(function(e) {
  nextPage();
  return e.preventDefaults();
});


});



//expired 

$(function() {
  var content3, isLoadingNextPage3, lastLoadAt3, loadNextPageAt3, minTimeBetweenPages3, viewMore3;
  content3 = $('#content-load-more-expired');
  viewMore3 = $('.view-more-expired');
  isLoadingNextPage3 = false;
  lastLoadAt3 = null; 
  minTimeBetweenPages3 = 5000;
  return loadNextPageAt3 = 1000;


var nextPage3;

nextPage3 = function() {
  var isLoadingNextPage3, lastLoadAt3, url3;
  url3 = viewMore3.find('a').attr('href');
  if (isLoadingNextPage3 || !url3) {
    return;
  }
  
  isLoadingNextPage3 = true;
  lastLoadAt3 = new Date();
  return $.ajax({
    url: url3,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function() {
      
      isLoadingNextPage3 = false;
      return lastLoadAt3 = new Date();
    }
  });
};

viewMore3.find('a').click(function(e) {
  nextPage3();
  return e.preventDefaults();
});


});
```

If its important to know whats inside my partials for `completed` and `pending` then here it is "ill keep it short" the other ones the same just with `pending`.

**_my_essays_completed.html.erb:**

```html
<% reservations_completed.each do |reservation| %>

<!-- content right here keepin it short -->

<% end %>
```

Comment: if you are using class, it will select all the members with the same class name. Try using ID

Comment: yes i Have tried this and i just tried again to make sure but still has some issues. i feel like the append and js or somthing.. :/..... its weird it doesnt append on the first click so far with a list of more than 2 pages worth.  but in the console it says that the` page_completed=2`.

Comment: Since I dont understand ruby that much, can you do a view source on your browser and paste the HTML instead.